# How to correctly delete items when relationships are involved?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This is some context about what I'm trying to do, I'm making a school survey system with surveys, and these surveys have sections that can be added to a certain survey, these sections have questions that belong to it, for example a section could be **Campus** and the questions in that section are related to the school campus.

I'm trying to delete a section and have all the questions that belong to that section be deleted as well, and my code does it half way. The questions have different "Categories" that are the response type, like a yes or no, ranking, text and finally a multiple choice question. For the questions that are multiple choice they have a relationship to the question options.

If a section doesn't have a multiple choice question inside then it deletes the section and all the questions, but if it does then I get this error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (unadeca_system.survey_question_options, CONSTRAINT survey_question_options_survey_question_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (survey_question_id) REFERENCES `survey_questions (id)) (SQL: delete from survey_questions where survey_questions.survey_section_id = 1 and survey_questions.survey_section_id is not null)

The relationships go like this

> Sections > hasMany > Questions > hasMany >QuestionOptions

I'm deleting like this in the section model

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    // when you are deleting a SurveySection, also delete all related questions
    static::deleting(function($section){
        $section->questions->each(function($question) {
            $question->surveyQuestionOption()->delete();
            $question->delete();
        });
    });
}
```

In the section controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $section = SurveySection::findOrFail($id);     
    $section->questions()->delete();
    $section->delete();
    DB::commit();

    return back();
}
```

This is how I'm deleting the questions from the model

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    // when you are deleting a SurveyQuestion, also delete all related options
    static::deleting(function($question){
        $question->surveyQuestionOption->each(function($option) {
            $option->delete();
        });
    });
}
```

This is how I'm deleting the questions in the controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $preg = SurveyQuestion::findOrFail($id);
    $preg->surveyQuestionOption()->delete();
    $preg->delete();
    DB::commit();

    return back();
}
```

How can I fix this error to delete all the questions irregardless of if it's multiple choice or not?

Comment: Try cascade deleting. You can do it at the migration level, or if you want to do it in your model, you should find all children of a record, delete them and then you can delete the parent.

Comment: @Bahman Ideally I want to do it from the model, I edited the question to add the other model deleting method as well

Comment: @Bahman I currently have my database to cascade delete but it's not working either

Comment: Which endpoint are you calling when failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `delete` on a Relationship object not an Eloquent Model:

```
$question->surveyQuestionOption()->delete();
```

This will end up calling the base Query Builder's `delete` method in the end to do a delete query directly; it does not call the `delete` method on the Model, which is what fires the Model events.

`SectionController@destroy`:

```
$section = SurveySection::findOrFail($id);

$section->delete();
```

`SurveySection@boot`:

```
static::deleting(function ($section) {
    $section->surveyQuestions->each(function ($question) {
        $question->delete();
    });
});
```

`SurveyQuestion@boot`:

```
static::deleting(function ($question) {
    $question->surveyQuestionOptions->each(function ($option) {
        $option->delete();
    });
});
```